# size of the node reflect the proportion of each topic

Tags: r, topic-modeling

[image]

Hi, How do I make the size of the node reflect the proportion of each topic? I am using stm package in R. Also, how to get the colours.

Comment: I haven't used the package before, but a quick look at the docs suggests that `vertex.color` and `vertex.size` might be the parameters you are looking for?